# MVC 2 Conversion Disrupts the parameters passed to my Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a few textboxes that are not required.  If the user enters nothing it is passed as 'null' in MVC 2.  It was passed as '""' in MVC 1.  What changes can I make to accomodate for this?

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Offer{ get; set; }
    public string AutoID { get; set; }


        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connections))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Info_Add", connect);
            command.Parameters.Add("autoID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", Name));

            //Offer now returns a null value, which cannot be passed
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("offer", Offer));
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            connect.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            AutoID = command.Parameters["autoID"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: please leave a comment when down voting, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the properties with [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) and if its true then set some default value to it.

This way it works both for ASP.NET MVC 1 and ASP.NET MVC 2

Comment: @jfar: sorry I didn't understand what u mean. what's wrong with the answer ?

Answer (score 12):

Change your model binder:

```
public class EmptyStringModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

and then in global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new EmptyStringModelBaseBinder();
```

This will revert to default settings from MVC 1. `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property is responsible for conversion to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to override the ModelBinder behaviour is to override the GetPropertyValue, this is where the ConvertEmptyStringToNull magic happens:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    class KeepEmptyStringsEmptyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
        {
            return propertyBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Brian